# Following tutorial openstack instal guide

Tags: installation, openstack, ubuntu-16.04

I am follwing this tutorial http://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/keystone-install.html

I dont pass on this part: 
Edit the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file and configure the ServerName option to reference the controller node: ServerName controller but I dont find ServerName in file apache2.conf It output error: unable to establish connection to http //controller:35357/v3/services

Comment: Are you on ubuntu xenial? Or debian jessie?

Comment: You can use the IP address of your node too. Did you add the a line in /etc/hosts to map "controller" to the actual ip?

Answer (score 0):

Add that directive in a new line, then restart apache2 service, then verify apache2 service is running.
Steps 2 and 3 in apache configuration are very important.